# Django custom middleware to check header token.Tests with valid request header tokens still fails

Tags: django, django-testing, django-middleware, django-tests

I am checking a request header for a valid token in my custom middleware.

```
class CustomTokenAuthentication(object):

def process_request(self, request):

    access_token = request.META.get('HTTP_TOKEN', '')
    if AccessToken.objects.filter(token=access_token).exists():
        return None
    else:
        # return None
        res =  HttpResponse("Invalid token", status=401)
        res["WWW-Authenticate"] = "Invalid Token"
        return res
```

seems to work fine, but im stuck writing a test by setting a header HTTP_TOKEN with a valid token value and geting a 200 response.

my sample testcode

```
def test_invalid_token_present(self):
    resp = self.client.get(reverse('productlist'), **{'HTTP_TOKEN':'8742627sdfsdfsf4e3423dsd23'})
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code,200)
```

seems to fail always.

Comment: try `HTTP-TOKEN` when sending the request.

Comment: sorry, try just `TOKEN` instead

Comment: still fails @EagerNoob

Comment: can you print the contents of `request.META.keys()` and check.

Comment: I meant try the header `TOKEN` in the request. I actually went ahead and tried it. If it doesn't work, then we'll have to look at the contents of `request.META`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django renames CUSTOM-HEADER to HTTP_CUSTOM_HEADER. When you send it `HTTP_TOKEN` it will get renamed to `HTTP_HTTP_TOKEN` in the `request.META` dict. A simple way to check what headers you are getting is to either print `request.META` and check the console or insert a `pdb` breakpoint just before the check and examin the `request.META` dict -  [link to relevant Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META%22django%20docs%22). So try:

```
    resp = self.client.get(reverse('productlist'),
                           **{'TOKEN':'8742627sdfsdfsf4e3423dsd23'})
```

I advise you to limit your line lengths, so that people don't have to scroll horizontally to read your code. PEP-8 prescribes an 80 character limit.